# How to reach object in an another class

Tags: java, oop

I have two classes in a same package which is very easy:

```
public class Cat {

String name;
int age;

public Cat(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

And in one class I implemented some cat:

```
public class CatImpl {

Cat first = new Cat("Black", 2);
Cat second = new Cat("White", 3);

public Cat getFirst() {
    return first;
}

public Cat getSecond() {
    return second;
}
}
```

And in my main class:

```
public class JavaApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //here
    }
}
```

Where I wrote "here" I like to call this for example:

```
first.getName(); 
or
first.setName("Luis");
```

Without this:

```
CatImpl b = new CatImpl();
```

Because if in an another class I implemented again a new CatImpl(); my changes ( for example: `first.setAge(4)` ) will lost. So I liked to reach this objects from lot of another class and set the variables without lost any changes.

Comment: You have to rethink your program structure. Basically it sounds like you are looking for a `Singleton`.

Comment: Looks like you haven't gone though the basics of object oriented programming, have you ? Just send the first `CatImpl` as an argument for the "another class" and you will be using the same `CatImpl` in both.

Comment: "Impl" typically means implantation. However, you seem to be using object composition, not implementation. If you want all Cat objects in that class to remain constant amongst all other classes, you are looking for a singleton pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define those cats as constants and access to them statically

```
public class CatImpl { 
public static final Cat first = new Cat("Black", 2); 
public static final Cat second = new Cat("White", 3); public Cat getFirst() {
```

And then

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

//here 
CatImpl.first... // this is a cat and is constant


}
```

Comment: You make those `final` ? Why ?

Comment: Am suggesting to define the cats as  constants

Comment: Then remove the final keyword

Comment: Then he can't set the name of the first cat to "Luis". I think my answer is much more appropiate.

Comment: @UDKOX you are able to modify a final object, you just can't reassign the reference

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `CatImpl cats = new CatImpl()` you are creating an object that contains 2 cats: `Black` and `White`. If you want other classes to use it, just give it to them. That's how object oriented programming works.

```
public class JavaApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CatImpl myCats = new CatImpl();
        myCats.getFirst().setName("Luis");

        ACatsUsingClass useCats = new ACatsUsingClass (myCats);
        useCats.printCats(); // This will print "Luis" and "White"
    }
}    


public class ACatsUsingClass {

    private CatImpls cats;

    public ACatsUsingClass (CatImpls cats ){
        this.cats = cats;
    }

    public void printCats(){
        System.out.println(cats.getFirst().getName());  // Prints "Luis"
        System.out.println(cats.getSecond().getName());  // Prints "White"  
    }
```